# Perl: Problems calling subroutines by reference using a hash value

Tags: perl, hash, reference, subroutine, callbyname

In Perl, you are able to call a function by reference (or name) like so:

```
    my $functionName = 'someFunction';
    &$functionName();

    #someFunction defined here:
    sub someFunction { print "Hello World!"; }
```

What I am trying to do is use a value from a Hash, like so:

```
    my %hash = (
        functionName => 'someFunction',
    );

    &$hash{functionName}();

    #someFunction defined here:
    sub someFunction { print "Hello World!"; }
```

And the error I get is Global symbol "$hash" requires explicit package name.

My question is: Is there a correct way to do this without using an intermediate variable?
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can also do `my %hash = ( function => \&someFunction )` which does not require `no strict 'refs'`.

Comment: @TLP +1, I was going to *answer* this. `use strict;` saves **so** much trouble...

Comment: I am able to use that, but it adds some somewhat-unreadable code (for now)... I am dynamically setting the value of functionName at runtime and calling a function by its name. Perl is so fun!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's just a precedence issue that can be resolved by not omitting the curlies. You could use

```
&{ $hash{functionName} }()
```

Or use the alternate syntax:

```
$hash{functionName}->()
```

As between indexes, the `->` can be omitted (but I don't omit it here):

```
$hash{functionName}()
```

Ref: [Deferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)

Comment: Wow, this is the first question I've ever asked on here, and was expecting a long wait. Thank you so much! I ended up using the first solution you posted.
Great stuff! Thank you so much.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention I am fairly-new to Perl (maybe one month of experience), so this will really help my professional development.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised because most people find the arrow notation most readable, but both are acceptable.

Comment: My reasoning is because somewhere (can't remember where) I read that you cannot pass in parameters without the ampersand when calling a function by name. I pass in parameters to other functions, so I wanted to keep it consistent.

Comment: That's not true at all. `$ref->(@args)` works perfectly line. `&$ref` (but not `&$ref()`) is very special, though. It reuses the parent's `@_`, something you normally want to avoid. Yet another reason to use `->()`. :)

Comment: I found out by just implementing it, and you are very correct, sir/ma'am.